# sort command in unix with numeric sort

Tags: sort

I have file1:

```
"$lvl=57"
"$lvl=20"
"$lvl=48"
"$lvl=17"
"$lvl=58"
```

File2 I want:

```
"$lvl=17"
"$lvl=20"
"$lvl=48"
"$lvl=57"
"$lvl=58"
```

Basically numerically sort of file1.

Comment: When I run a plain Unix `sort` on your File1, with no options, I get your File2. What are you doing differently?  What are you leaving out of this question?

Answer (score 51):

I like the `-V` / `--version-sort` option found in a few implementations of `sort` (from GNU `sort`): it behaves very well for many situations mixing strings and numbers

```
sort -V
```

I use this option very often...

In the same direction, with some implementations of `ls`,  `ls -v` for version-sort `ls` (from GNU `ls`).

Answer (score 17):

You need to tell `sort -n` to sort on the part after the `=`:

```
sort -t = -k 2n
```

Comment: @KasiyA `-k` defines a sort key. See the man page for details. `-k2n` defines a sort key starting at the second field and ending at the end of the line and makes it a numeric sort key.

Answer (score 5):

I found that, you just run `sort -h`, it will work. They call it `--human-numberic-sort`.

```
sort -h file1 > file2
```

Comment: Can't edit due to the strike — the options are `-h` and `--human-numeric-sort`

Answer (score 0):

use sort:

```
sort -n file1 > file2
```

-n, --numeric-sort
              compare according to string numerical value

```
 sort -g file1 > file 2
```

-g, --general-numeric-sort

Comment: No, all those lines have the same ranking with `sort -n` since they don't start with a number. The reason it sorts them is the last-resort full-line sort (lexically, not numerically) done for lines with the same ranking. That would sort `"$lvl=17"` before `"$lvl=2"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for pointing out.

Comment: To paraphrase, `-n` and `-g` are redundant here as the input is not numerical. So this answer is misleading, hence the downvote (also note that `-g` and the long options are GNU specific).

Comment: but -g is good general-numeric-sort

Comment: That's still for sorting numerical values, the difference with `-n` is that it's not limited to decimal integers. That would still sort `"$lvl=17"` before `"$lvl=2"` as part of the last-resort sorting.

Comment: @Hackaholic: `-g` is not a general-purpose numerical sort. It's much slower than the plain `-n` numeric sort, but `-g` can handle scientific notation, which is not needed here. See the info page of sort for more details.