# sorting numerically in unix

Tags: shell, sort

I have question about sorting files,and my question is different from other questions about sorting
I have a folder including hundereds of files looks like this

```
anacovaux_1052_summary_betai.out
anacovaux_1052_summary_Pdelta.out
anacovaux_1052_summary_pij.out
anacovaux_1053_DIC.out
anacovaux_1053_summary_betai.out
anacovaux_1053_summary_beta_params.out
anacovaux_1048_DIC.out
anacovaux_1048_summary_betai.out
anacovaux_1043_summary_pi_xtx.out
anacovaux_1058_DIC.out
```

I wanted to know is there any way that I could sort them numerically? I mean get something like this:

```
anacovaux_1043_summary_pi_xtx.out
anacovaux_1048_DIC.out
anacovaux_1048_summary_betai.out
anacovaux_1052_summary_betai.out
anacovaux_1052_summary_Pdelta.out
anacovaux_1052_summary_pij.out
anacovaux_1053_DIC.out
anacovaux_1053_summary_betai.out
anacovaux_1053_summary_beta_params.out
anacovaux_1058_DIC.out
```

Comment: Does all the files have the same filename prefix and is the number always 4 digits? If yes, then `ls` should sort them already, as would `echo *` and `printf '%s\n' *`.

Comment: Please give a sample that doesn't sort already in the order you want with `ls` or GNU `ls -v`. For instance, do you want `B_1.out` to sort before `A_2.out`? You'd want `A2` to sort before `A10` I presume?

Comment: See also [sort in Unix  with numeric sort](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169200/80216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ls` from GNU coreutils (default on most Linux systems):

```
$ ls -v -1
```

This will list the filenames in one single column (`-1`), sorted using the natural sort order for numbers within the filename ("version sorting", `-v`).  This assumes that all filenames have the same prefix string up to the actual number (`anacovaux_` for example).

For systems without GNU `ls`:

```
$ print '%s\n' * | sort -t '_' -k2,2n
```

This will sort the names on the number after the first `_` character in the name.  Again, it assumes that the filename prefix is constant (this solution totally *ignores* the prefix up to the first `_`).

Comment: Yes, @Kusalananda thank you so much, gives the same output that I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list files in a folder in custom sort order:

```
ls -1 yourfolder | sort -t'_' -k2,2n
```

Comment: What the OP wrote is actually irrelevant in this case... Again, `-1` is _not needed here_ because `ls` by default prints one entry per line with a few exceptions ("output is a terminal" being one of them). Does any of the mods know _why_ has my previous comment vanished ?

Comment: @don_crissti, I don't see a critical problem here with using `-1` option to adjust the output (print only filenames)

Comment: thank you.@RomanPerekhrest it does the job partially for me. I have some files like anacovaux_105_DIC.out.  So when I use your code it comes after anacovaux_1048_summary_betai.out....Is there any solution for that? Indeed my file are from 1-2181. I just presented a few of them as an example

Comment: @Anna1364, just add `n` (natural sorting) flag to `sort` command. I couldn't give you this answer fast (6 ours ago) cause we are in different time zones